# Masking a directory with htaccess and blocking the original

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have used the following code to mask a directory;

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule libs(.*) wp-content/$1 [L]
```

I want the server to show a 404 error if the original directory is requested but allow the access if the masked URL is used.

For example;

The user goes to /wp-content/something.html in their browser and gets a 404 error,
but if the user instead goes to /libs/something.html the file shows correctly.

This rule needs to apply to everyone but localhost.

I have tried this code but it doesn't work as the request uri is changed when the mask takes place.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-content
RewriteRule ^wp-content/ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: How about using a symlink `libs -> wp-content` you do not need a rewrite rule for the libs request any more and apply your rule for direct wp-content requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `THE_REQUEST` instead which represents original request to Apache:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} wp-content
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```